# Using a filter web part to filter document librarys

Tags: sharepoint-online, connected-web-parts, connection-filters

I have a wiki page with 3 web parts. A choice filter web part and 2 document librarys(library1 & library2). library1 contains documents displayed in a list view. Library2 contains folders and sub folders. both document librarys have a common field "email_address" which is used by the choice filter to filter both document library web parts. the filter works fine and filters results as expected but when i click into a folder on the library2 webpart i get an error displayed in the library1 web part

> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.
>   Correlation ID:30c9ce9d-f0e1-3000-e0c2-4335b1b75b1e

Has anyone else experienced this issue and is there a workaround for it ?
I am using sharepoint 2013 online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be be an issue with having a sub folder structure view on a web part which has a web part filter applied to it. once you click into a folder it removes the filtering/ and or gives you an error.
My work around for this was to create a new view for the web part which shows all files, this view does not show folders or sub folders content types. The option is in the view settings under folders check the option for "show items inside folders"